# ZedGraph different line colors

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I wanna change the line color permanently if points > 100; I mean i wanna see Red lines on graph for data are greater than 100 and green for data is smaller than 100. How can i do this?

[image]

I want red lines for data range inside rectangle, if it is possible.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Gradient-By-Value](http://zedgraph.dariowiz.com/index014f.html?title=Gradient-By-Value_Demo) example chart. That chart uses the third coordinate (Z) to indicate the color of a point, by setting:

```
curve.Symbol.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByZ;
```

Similarly, you can use `GradientByY` to indicate that y-axis values should be used. It seems however, that if `RangeMin` and `RangeMax` are equal, wrong color will be applied to the entire chart, so you need to make them differ by a relatively small value.

```
curve.Symbol.Fill = new Fill( Color.Green, Color.Red );
curve.Symbol.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByY;
curve.Symbol.Fill.RangeMin = 100 - 1e-3;
curve.Symbol.Fill.RangeMax = 100;
```

Comment: I am not using Symbol to show points. I just want to see different line colors for values between 80 and 100. It is threshold value.

Comment: Oh, ok got it. This means you would have lines split in half sometimes, with one line having two differently colored parts. I don't think ZedGraph supports it out of the box, I'll take a look at it again.

Comment: @Blast: have you tried setting `curve.Line.Fill` instead of `curve.Symbol.Fill`? I see that it uses this while drawing, although I think it doesn't properly render split lines.

Comment: curve.Line.Color = Color.Red; I tried this code. I think the problem is about my condition. 
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                list.Add(time, (double)data[i]);
                if (data[i] > 100)
                {
                    curve.Line.Color = Color.Red;
                }
            }

It changes the color of the all lines or it fills whole curve with color in graph.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to change the color of few points in the curve, but you can change the color of a region using [BoxObject](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_BoxObj.htm) of Zedgraph.

Try the following:

```
 private void drawRegion()
    {
        GraphPane pane = zedGraphControl1.GraphPane;

        BoxObj box = new BoxObj(0, 20, 500, 10,Color.Empty, Color.LightYellow);

        box.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
        box.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Left;
        box.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Top;

        // place the box behind the axis items, so the grid is drawn on top of it
        box.ZOrder = ZOrder.E_BehindCurves;
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(box);

        // Add Region text inside the box 
        TextObj myText = new TextObj("Threshold limit", 100, 15);
        myText.Location.CoordinateFrame = CoordType.AxisXYScale;
        myText.Location.AlignH = AlignH.Right;
        myText.Location.AlignV = AlignV.Center;
        myText.FontSpec.IsItalic = true;
        myText.FontSpec.FontColor = Color.Red;
        myText.FontSpec.Fill.IsVisible = false;
        myText.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
        pane.GraphObjList.Add(myText);

        zedGraphControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I will try it as soon as possible.